# Create Silverlight Bing Maps Shapes from GML

Tags: silverlight, bing-maps, gml

So I have spatial data stored in an SQL Server 2008 database (zip codes). My frontend is Silverlight 4 and I can get the shapes from the WCF service to the frontend as GML. 
Is there any easy way to add them as shapes to the map without parsing the GML myself? Or could I use well known text format instead?
I cannot use an RSS service for various other reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the spatial functions in odata for  this. Its in the wcf data services October preview.

Answer (score 0):

Use WKT. if you need to extract data from geometry types. Add sql types as reference to your project and use sql geometry types.